# Where to start with SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, nosql

I learned several languages such as Python, C/C++, Java, C# and took algorithm classes. I want to learn how to use SQL with those languages. 
Here's what I want to ask about:
What are the differences between SQL, MySQL, SQLite, MongoDB, NoSQL and which one do I start to learn and why?

Comment: 3.5 years on this site and this is what ya got for us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the differences between SQL, MySQL, SQLite, MongoDB, NoSQL?

> SQL stands for Structured Query Language,you can communicate with databases using SQL. in other words SQL is a special-purpose programming language designed for managing data held in a database.
>   Others MySQL, SQLite, MongoDB, NoSQL are databases

which one do I start to learn and why?

> Answer of this question is it is upto you and your project's requirement or you can say which one is best suited to your project.